# How to reference parameter of a higher kinded type parameteter?

Tags: scala, generics

Suppose you have a trait like this:

```scala
trait Foo[A]{
    def foo: A
}
```

I want to create a function like this:

```scala
def getFoo[A <: Foo[_]](a: A) = a.foo
```

The Scala Compiler deduces `Any` for the return type of this function.
How can I reference the anonymous parameter `_` in the signature (or body) of `getFoo`?
In other words, how can I un-anonymize the parameter?

I want to be able to use the function like

```scala
object ConcreteFoo extends Foo[String] {
  override def foo: String = "hello"
}

val x : String = getFoo(ConcreteFoo)
```

which fails compilation for obvious reasons, because `getFoo` is implicitly declared as `Any`.

If this is not possible with Scala (2.12 for that matter), I'd be interested in the rational or the technical reason for this limitation.
I am sure there are articles and existing questions about this, but I appear to be lacking the correct search terms.

---

**Update:** The existing answer accurately answers my question as stated, but I suppose I wasn't accurate enough regarding my actual usecase. Sorry for the confusion. I want to be able to write

```scala
def getFoo[A <: Foo[_]] = (a: A) => a.foo

val f = getFoo[ConcreteFoo.type]

//In some other, unrelated place
val x = f(ConcreteFoo)
```

Because I don't have a parameter of type `A`, the compiler can't deduce the parameters `R` and `A` if I do

```scala
def getFoo[R, A <: Foo[R]]: (A => R) = (a: A) => a.foo
```

like suggested. I would like to avoid manually having to supply the type parameter `R` (`String` in this case), because it feels redundant.

Comment: They call it "anonymous" exactly for the reason that it has no name, and therefore cannot be referenced. So, "de-anonymize" literally means "give it a name": `def getFoo[B, A <: Foo[B]](a: A): B = a.foo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer literally your exact question:

```
def getFoo[R, A <: Foo[R]](a: A): R = a.foo
```

But since you don't make any use of the type `A`, you can actually omit it and the `<: Foo[..]` bound completely, retaining only the return type:

```
def getFoo[R](a: Foo[R]): R = a.foo
```

---

**Update** (the question has been changed quite significantly)

You could smuggle in an additional `apply` invocation that infers the return type from a separate implicit return type witness:

```
trait Foo[A] { def foo: A }

/** This is the thing that remembers the actual return type of `foo`
  * for a given `A <: Foo[R]`.
  */
trait RetWitness[A, R] extends (A => R)

/** This is just syntactic sugar to hide an additional `apply[R]()`
  * invocation that infers the actual return type `R`, so you don't
  * have to type it in manually.
  */
class RetWitnessConstructor[A] {
  def apply[R]()(implicit w: RetWitness[A, R]): A => R = w
}

def getFoo[A <: Foo[_]] = new RetWitnessConstructor[A]
```

Now it looks almost like what you wanted, but you have to provide the implicit, and you have to call `getFoo[ConcreteFoo.type]()` with additional pair of round parens:

```
object ConcreteFoo extends Foo[String] {
  override def foo: String = "hey"
}

implicit val cfrw = new RetWitness[ConcreteFoo.type, String] {
  def apply(c: ConcreteFoo.type): String = c.foo
}

val f = getFoo[ConcreteFoo.type]()
val x: String = f(ConcreteFoo)
```

I'm not sure whether it's really worth it, it's not necessarily the most straightforward thing to do. Type-level computations with implicits, hidden behind somewhat subtle syntactic sugar: that might be too much magic hidden behind those two parens `()`. Unless you expect that the return type of `foo` will change very often, it might be easier to just add a second generic argument to `getFoo`, and write out the return type explicitly.

Comment: Okay, this was quick and easy. Thank you. I suppose my MCVE wasn't accurate enough regarding my actual usecase. I added an example for my usecase, would you be able to expand your answer on that?

Comment: @LukeG Yes, this can be done too. So many strange things can be done with Scala's type system... Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing addition. For now I decided that it is indeed not really worth it. I tried to use it with parser combinators where The return type of `getFoo[A]` isn't `A => R`, but `Parser[R]`. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but apparently it only gets worse.

Comment: @LukeG Parser combinators are usually used in similar contexts in a similar way, and they usually look roughly the same. I've never felt the need for something like what you've attempted here when using parser combinators. Maybe it's an XY-problem.

Comment: Let's say it's a simple problem made unneccesarily complicated. For (more or less mandatory) academic reasons I have a separate Scanner and Parser. The Scanner generates `List[Token]`. Some tokens extend `trait ValueToken[A]{def value: A}` (literals mostly, i.e. tokens with a "value" opposed to keywords and delimiters). Whenever I use these tokens in a grammar rule I wanted to have it as simple as possible. Being the perefectionist I am I wanted to have it in a generic way for every `T <: ValueToken[_]` instead of writing it out.

Comment: I resorted to explicitly writing a line like`def IDENT: Parser[String] = getValue[String, tokens.IDENTIFIER]` for every single (read: all three) `T <: ValueToken[_]`. This is short, clean, works, and causes less headache.